# How would I Group by a specific day and then find the total sum of a column using R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

**Objective:**

I have a dataset, df, that consists of a Date and a Duration column. I am wanting to determine the total duration within a day. I am trying to figure out how to group by day and find this sum:

```
Duration    Date

 35        1/23/2020 6:04:40 AM
 12        1/23/2020 10:12:28 PM
 76        1/16/2020 6:21:48 PM
 34        1/21/2020 7:54:38 PM
 166       1/23/2020 7:03:37 PM
 4         1/21/2020 9:43:26 PM
 72        1/16/2020 6:23:20 PM
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Date              Duration (seconds)

1/16/2020         148
1/21/2020         38
1/23/2020         213
```

**Here is the dput:**

```
(list(Duration = c(35L, 12L, 76L, 34L, 166L, 4L, 72L
), Date = structure(c(6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("1/16/2020 6:21:48 PM", 
"1/16/2020 6:23:20 PM", "1/21/2020 7:54:38 PM", "1/21/2020 9:43:26 PM", 
"1/23/2020 10:12:28 PM", "1/23/2020 6:04:40 AM", "1/23/2020 7:03:37 PM"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

**This is what I have tried:**

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(lubridate)

 df%>%
 groupby(Date) %>%
 summarize(Duration)
```

However, how would I groupby the actual day?
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Voting to close because it needs more focus. Asking for a solution in `r` or `python` makes it too broad.

Comment: ok let me rephrase please

Comment: The `lubridate` package can help here: `df %>% group_by(date=lubridate::date(lubridate::mdy_hms(Date))) %>% summarize(duration=sum(Duration))`

Comment: thank you! @MrFlick this works!

Comment: @MrFlick, I mis-understood the question. You should post your answer.